# Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac Publish Option

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, publish, visual-studio-community

Is it possible to publish a .net application with Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac?
It seems that not, the option doesn't appear in the project properties tab.
Maybe this is to force us to by the professional version.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It does have Publish menu item. It's under Build, not Project. Although, it quite limited for now. It can only publish to Azure. I still can't generate deployable package so I can deploy it on my own VPS. I have to resort to command line for that.

[image: The Publish is under Build menu, instead of Project menu]

Answer (score 0):

Your Console .NETCore program is already compiled use `$mono program.exe` to execute it.